# Why do Stack Exchange staff use their real names?

Tags: discussion, privacy

I was wondering why Stack Exchange staff use their real names, e.g. the community managers, Rob, Tim, and Shog (if he replies to an email).  Shouldn't the same safety / privacy considerations be the same for them, as it is for us "normal" users?  There are probably tens of thousands of people who use the network everyday - what if some of them are physically dangerous people, and have more than just a loud mouth on the Internet?  Just curious ...

Comment: Well, other CM's who use their online names like JNat, animuson. Shog's real name is Josh. I think Hairboat is also not the real name.

Comment: You never know if Jeff Atwood is really Jeff Atwood. He may actually be called anything you could think of: God, Dios, Deux, whatever.

Comment: Few (most?) of the Stack Overflow Moderators have had such incidents, where they suspended a user, and that user became violent IRL.

Comment: @BhargavRao, I see ... hence my question.  I feel safe using a name that's ... kinda obviously not my own.  But why should SE staff be less safe than us, by using their real names, for company transparency or whatnot?  Although JourneymanGeek (see his answer below) and iDebug mention that the names are merely identities and doesn't imply that those are their real names.  And so, Tim Post might not actually be Tim Post in real life, Josh might not be Shog in real life ...

Comment: Fun Fact. My legal name is shared with someone *significantly* more famous, or infamous. So's my dog's. And... well, what someone can do with a name alone, IMO is somewhat limited. *if* there's a real/credible threat, its something for the cops.

Comment: FYI, **My REAL name is *Carlton The Doorman***

Comment: Actually, Jeff's real name is Jessica, but she knows how badly women in tech, especially online, can be treated, so she created the "Jeff" alias.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I was gonna start worrying about folks showing up at my door threatening physical violence, I'd start with my neighbors (because some of them have actually done that).

For trolls online, there are... a different set of primary concerns.

[image]

Comment: Who moved away? You or the neighbors?

Answer (score 4):

Not everyone does - and a lot of CMs do actually use their handles.

More practically, its the same *identity* many of them use/used as regular users on the network. A lot of staff, after all have a long history with the network.

There might be some department specific traditions (lots of SREs use their real names, for example) but there's no real official policy I know of.

I suppose when emailing as a representitive of SO Inc, its just standard professionalism.

Comment: If your real name were Journey, haha.

Comment: SE's actually sent me mail to the name. Confused the postman ;p

Answer (score 4):

Some do, some don't -- same as for moderators and other users.

Some of it is probably precedent.  Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood created Stack Overflow and used their real names.  So did Geoff Dalgas and Jarrod Dixon, the first two programmers who worked on it.  I remember reading, but cannot now find, a blog post by Joel back then in which he *encouraged* people to use their real names, I think so that their online reputation (on SO) could more-easily influence their offline (job) reputation.

Comment: @shog9 Whoops.  I even had the blog post open in front of me while I was misspelling those names.  Sheesh.